# knockout.js data-bind doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I'm new no knockout.js and try to apply it, but simple things don't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        name: ko.observable("test")
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
```

I see no any text, but in debugger context (with not trimmed whitespace for some reason):

```
" name": "test"
```

also there is `$data` with declared `name: function observable()`

What I do wrong?

Comment: applyBindings can't be called until the DOM is rendered - move the script to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

You want to have your code like this instead:

```
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        name: ko.observable("test")
    }
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Always ensure you apply you bindings at the end of your html or once document has rendered/loaded.